# How do I get a DbContext that has SubmitChanges and lets me get a table like context.MyTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to figure out if maybe the `DbContext` I'm referencing in my application is an old one. I'm used to there being a `SubmitChanges` function -- it even shows up in the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx -- and I'm used to being able to access tables like `context.SomeTable` and that isn't working. I did *Go To Definition* in my code and got

```
#region Assembly EntityFramework.dll, v6.0.0.0
\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll
#endregion
```

ad the top and when I looked the functions I didn't see `SubmitChanges` like I would expect to.

Comment: Are you using DB first or Code First? can you show us your context class?

Answer (score 0):

SubmitChanges is a method of the LINQ to SQL DataContext derived classes.

In DbContext derived classes, the method name is SaveChanges